# configurar header en axios

Tags: http, axios

estoy teniendo un problema con axios, la aplicación tiene un sistema de sesión, cuando intento iniciar sesión mando los datos al backend mediante un objeto, pero dentro de la aplicación tengo varios formularios y estoy enviando esos formularios mediante el objeto `FormData`, esta es la configuración del Content-Type:

```
'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
```

pero cuando uso el `FormData` estos que envio al backend no se visualiza, necesito saber si puedo o como puedo hacer para hacer algo como esto:

```
'Content-Type' : 'application/json multipart/form-data'
```

intente agregar otro `Content-Type` a la configuración pero no se puede

Comment: ¿Ya probaste de esta forma https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format?

Comment: usar el content-type por defecto que tiene axios?